# checkboxlist multiple selection in db yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Learned a lot about my question, and didn't figure it out. I need to write two or more values in the database from `checkboxList()`
In my view `activeForm`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'quant[]')->checkboxList([
                        'one' => 'one',
                        'two' => 'two',
                        'three' => 'three',
                        'four' => 'four'], 
                        ['separator' => '<br>']); ?>
```

So after create no matter how much values I choose, only one will add in db. 
I realized that I need to get an array in the controller and then it will save in the database. Something like this:

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {

        $model = new TakMol();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $model->quant=implode(',',$_POST['TakMol']['quant']); //change items into string to be saved

            return $this->redirect(['index']);

        } else {
            $model->quant=explode(',',$model->quant); //string to array to fill the checkboxlist

            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,

            ]);
        }

    }
```

Maybe I need to do something like this in `actionCreate`

```
$post=Yii::$app->request->post();
        $checkbox = array_keys ($post);
        foreach ($checkbox as $value){
            $model = new TakMol();              
                     $model->quant = $model->id;  
                     $model->quant = $value;
                     $model->save();
        }
```

I tried and other options, it didn't work out. I will be grateful for help in solving.

[**_form(cell)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwlqu.jpg)  [**index(cell)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IXXM.jpg)

Comment: Did not your question properly.what you want to do.And what is current output.

Comment: In `CRUD`  `_form` I need to multiple select checkboxes when I create a form. Then in my db(same in index `GridView` column `quant`) I get entered values. For example: add img _form(cell) I select `Quant: 1,3,4`. After form create it returns only one(first) value, add img index(cell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a form model as support for extra field for base model, you can handle this task inside this new class.

Put TakMolForm.php file inside the same folder of TakMol.php:

```
class TakMolForm extends TakMol
{
      private $_quantArray;

      public function getQuantArray()
      {
           // Initialize it from 'quant' attribute
           if($this->_quantArray == null) 
           {
                 $this->_quantArray = explode(',', $this->quant);
           }
           return $this->_quantArray;
      }

      public function setQuantArray($value)
      {
           $this->_quantArray = $value;
      }


      public function rules()
      {
          return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
                   [['quantArray'], 'safe'],

          ]);
       }       
}
```

Then in controller change TakMol in TakMolForm:

```
public function saveModel($model)
{
    // Here is called getQuantArray() getter from TakMolForm model
    $model->quant = implode(',', $model->quantArray);

    return $model->save();    
}

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new TakMolForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $this->saveModel($model)) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

 }

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = TakMolForm::findOne($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $this->saveModel($model)) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Finally in the view you will use quantArray field instead quant:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'quantArray')->checkboxList([
                        'one' => 'one',
                        'two' => 'two',
                        'three' => 'three',
                        'four' => 'four'], 
                        ['separator' => '<br>']); ?>
```

Comment: I try to use your answer, and in TakMolForm.php has an error: `syntax error, unexpected 'getQuantArray' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)`
If i set `public getQuantArray()` -> `public $getQuantArray()` returns `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'`. I tried a couple variations, but have same result. What that error can be ?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed 'function' after public ... so It is 'public function getQuantArray' ... make same thing for 'serQuantArray'... i have updated  source code

Comment: Oh my, it works perfect! Thank you so much! Finally after your update with `...Array` I understand how the code works.

Comment: Also has one more question, if in the `_form` is another cell with a `checkboxlist()`, I need `v1`: to create a new `TakMolForm2.php` and in controller add after `$model = new TakMolForm();` `$model = new TakMolForm2();`. Or `v2`: in the `TakMolForm.php`, repeat  `private... and two functions` but with other name, then in rule `[['quantArray', 'quantArray2'], 'safe'],` ?

Comment: Repeat same solution also for the other field